# Declaring variables of a type nested inside a template argument?

Tags: c++, templates

I had success in passing a class into a template method. However, if the class has structures inside, the c++ compiler does not recognize the argument of general type T as a class and does not permit use of :: operator to access to the structures within the class. I tired a variation of coding and it did not work. Please consider that I am doing this to be able to pass a generic class, any class, into this method and I wouldn't like to instantiate a certain class in the process otherwise I wouldn't come to use a template:

```
     class IO
     {

      public:

        struct Input 
        { 
          double pressure = 100;
        };

        struct Output
        {
         double pressure = 110;
        };

      };

       template <class T>           
       bool B::MethodBT(T IO)

       {

         IO::Input In;
         IO::Output Out;
         Out.pressure = In.pressure * 10;
         cout << "In Template P= :"<< Out.pressure<<endl;
         return true;

       }
```

Comment: You'd need to write `T::Input`, but it would probably require `typename T::Input`

Comment: A hint: classes **are** structures in C++ and vice versa.

Comment: I don't see any template in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at what you have here:

```
   template <class T> bool B::MethodBT(T IO) {
     IO::Input In;   // Error!
     IO::Output Out; // Error!
```

The issue here is that `IO` is a variable, not a type, so you can't apply the scope resolution operator to it. The type of `IO`, `T`, is a type, so you could start by trying to rewrite it like this:

```
   template <class T> bool B::MethodBT(T IO) {
     T::Input In;   // Better, but error!
     T::Output Out; // Better, but error!
```

If this is the case, congratulations, you've just discovered *dependent type names*! In C++, a type name is called *dependent* if the type in question is nested inside of a template argument or otherwise depends on some computation on a template type argument. Here, `T::Input` is a dependent name because `Input` is nested inside of `T`, which is a template parameter.

To fix this, you can use the `typename` keyword like this:

```
   template <class T> bool B::MethodBT(T IO) {
     typename T::Input In;   // Better!
     typename T::Output Out; // Better!
```

In other words, the name of the type of `In` is `typename T::Input`.

Any time you need to use a dependent name, you have to prefix it with the `typename` keyword. This is a common stumbling block when you're first learning templates - in fact, I remember having that same issue! - so modern compilers are starting to issue error messages that will explicitly suggest that you go and do this.

Comment: Hi, I just changed to   T::Input In; and T::Output Out; and it is working now. I used  template <class T>  so I suppose my typename is class which probably is not necessary to add. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Answer updated. This should fix the issue you're seeing, unless there's something else going on that you didn't mention in the original question.

Comment: Works! Thanks again!